# Is there a way to generate c# code from serialized object in bson (file on a disk) to

Tags: c#, json, code-generation, json.net, bson

What I have is a serialized object (given to me serialized from another language). I would like to generate c# code for this and use it in JSON.Net or similar. I have just started looking at JSON.Net capabilities. However, thought it may be interesting to ask it here in parallel.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are getting at, but why does that other language not just give you the object in JSON instead?

Comment: This is something not in my control. The object is given to me in a serialized format dumped to file. The end result I am looking for is a code generated c# class which can deserialize the bson object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found 2 great options:

[json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) works well, which is a lightweight website giving .NET code that can be copy-pasted.

[JsonCSharpClassGenerator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/) is an executable that creates actual files in a subfolder of your choosing. So it's better for bulk .NET class generation from a large JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the list here, there are several BSON implementations for C#:

http://bsonspec.org/#/implementation

One example is [JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/12/26/json-net-3-5-release-6-binary-json-bson-support.aspx).

Comment: I have already looked at it. There are many which allow to serialize the objects. Infact, I am almost decided on using FastJSON to do deserialization. However, the question is what type do i deserialize into? There is NO existing C# code for the type. I have to either write it (which does not scale as there are many types I have to consider) or generate it from bson file given to me.

Comment: Look at using Mongo, I think it uses expando objects to give you dynamic object creation at runtime. But, then you have the problem of knowing which properties, methods you should be using once you have your object...

Comment: Dynamic object creation at runtime will not work for me. This is costly in performance and will not scale well. This code needs to go into a service where latency is crucial (not Real time,but needs to be as low as possible).